# What is Rails include/render equivalent when I want text passed through, not interpreted as ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have some browser-side template code to include in a page that gets served. This is for a backbone.js driven page that uses templating (on the client/javascript side). I put the following code in a partial to test it out. I want this code to be passed through as-is to the browser.

```
<script type="text/template" id="stats-template">
    <% if (total) { %>
        <span class="todo-count">
          <span class="number"><%= remaining %></span>
          <span class="word"><%= remaining == 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %></span> left.
        </span>
    <% } %>
    <% if (done) { %>
        <span class="todo-clear">
          <a href="#">
              Clear <span class="number-done"><%= done %></span>
              completed <span class="word-done"><%= done == 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %></span>
          </a>
        </span>
    <% } %>
</script>
```

The problem is that if I use `<%= render 'manage_application_templates'  %>` in my erb template, rails tries to interpret the rendered code as ruby/erb (i.e. paying attention to `<%...%>`).

What I want is for it to 'dumbly' pass through the contents of that partial and serve it to the browser. Escaping anything in the partial seems ugly. In searching around, I could not find a dumb alternative to render or any options that would make render behave how I want. Am I missing something obvious (likely, yes).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why don't you include jst right in your page?

Comment: Are you asking why wouldn't I include that block of code in the page? I have no issue with that, but there is the same issue that it gets interpreted as ERB (which I don't want).

Comment: I've adopted this kind of organization: http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/6/28/where-does-my-javascript-code-go-backbone-jst-and-the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline

Comment: (tell me if it answers, if so I'll post it as an answer)

Comment: Thanks much for the pointer. That article is very useful, but I can't say that it answers my original quesiton. It probably handles my issue overall.

Comment: It's my opinion, and I always prefer solving the root of problems

Answer (score 1):

```
render :text => 'sometext'
```

For the complete documentation visit:
http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464

Answer (score 0):

All files ended with ".erb" will be interpreted by ERB, files without ".erb" are not interpreted.

just rename your file.

Comment: That's what I thought. I had named the file '.html' without the '.erb'. It still tries to interpret it. The only thing I have been able to do is escape, i.e. `<%%...%>` instead of `<%...%>`